# How to get hash from document url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if I use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      console.log($(this));

});
```

then in console I have object:

```
[Document mypage.html#weather]
```

how can i get for this last ID? In this example this is **#weather**. I would like use alert **#weather** in selector, for example `$(data_from_console + '.add').val();`

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. When you say you would like to "alert #weather" do you mean in the console or with an `alert("#weather")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to get the last element that has an ID attribute?

If so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($('body *[id]').eq(-1));
});
```

**EDIT**
On a closer look, are you looking for the hash tag? ie. if your URL is `mypage.html#weather` you want the #weather ?

In that case try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(document.location.hash);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body *').each(function() { //selects all elements in body which got id
      var lastEle = $(this).last();   //selects last one of them
      console.log(lastEle.attr('id'));//returns it's id to console log
    });
});
```